# get and set monitor brightness level on windows

Tags: windows, screen-brightness

We'd like to get/set brightness level of monitors on Windows.  We can't find any sample code that works.  We keep getting NULL handles from the GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR().  Can anyone provide sample code that works for Windows 7 and later?  We've searched and searched for working code sample and can't find anything.  See below the code we have tried (among many).

```
typedef struct {
    float * get ;
    float const * set ;
} enum_info_t ;

static
BOOL CALLBACK monitor_callback(
  HMONITOR hMonitor,
  HDC      hdcMonitor,
  LPRECT   lprcMonitor,
  LPARAM   dwData
) {
    BOOL ok ;
    enum_info_t * const info = (enum_info_t *) dwData ;
    eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:hMonitor=%p info=%p\n", hMonitor, info) ;

    DWORD nmonitor ;
    LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pPhysicalMonitors = NULL;

    /* Get the number of physical monitors.
     */
    ok = GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(
      hMonitor, 
      &nmonitor) ;

    eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:num_monitors ok=%d count=%ld\n",
        ok, nmonitor) ;

    if (!ok ||
    !nmonitor) {
    goto done ;
    }

    /* Allocate the array of PHYSICAL_MONITOR structures.
     */
    pPhysicalMonitors =
    (LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR) malloc(nmonitor * sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR)) ;

    if (!pPhysicalMonitors) {
    goto done ;
    }

    ok = GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(
    hMonitor, nmonitor, pPhysicalMonitors);

    /* Use the monitor handles (not shown).
     */
    if (ok) {
    for (unsigned ofs=0;ofs<nmonitor;ofs++) {
        LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pmonitor = &pPhysicalMonitors[ofs] ;
        QString tmp =
        QString::fromWCharArray(pmonitor->szPhysicalMonitorDescription) ;
        seaiq_string_t tmp_s ;

        eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:monitor[%d] handle=%p description=%s\n",
            ofs, pmonitor->hPhysicalMonitor,
            tmp_s = QString_to_string(tmp)) ;
        seaiq_string_free(tmp_s) ;

        DWORD caps = 0 ;
        DWORD temps = 0 ;
        ok = GetMonitorCapabilities(pmonitor->hPhysicalMonitor, &caps, &temps) ;

        eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:monitor[%d] ok=%d brightness=%d none=%d\n", ofs, ok,
            (caps & MC_CAPS_BRIGHTNESS) != 0,
            (caps & MC_CAPS_NONE) != 0) ;

        DWORD min = 0 ;
        DWORD cur = 0 ;
        DWORD max = 0 ;
        ok = GetMonitorBrightness(
        pmonitor->hPhysicalMonitor, &min, &cur, &max) ;

        eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:monitor[%d] ok=%d min=%lu cur=%lu max=%lu\n",
            ofs, ok, min, cur, max) ;
    }

    LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pmonitor = &pPhysicalMonitors[0] ;

    DWORD min = 0 ;
    DWORD cur = 0 ;
    DWORD max = 0 ;
    ok = GetMonitorBrightness(
        pmonitor->hPhysicalMonitor, &min, &cur, &max) ;

    eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:GetMonitorBrightness:ok=%d min=%lu cur=%lu max=%lu\n",
        ok, min, cur, max) ;

    if (ok) {
        if (info->get && min < max && min <= cur && cur <= max) {
        *info->get =
            ((float)cur - (float)min) /
            ((float)max - (float)min) ;
        eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:get:%.3f\n", *info->get) ;
        }

        if (info->set) {
        DWORD dwv = *info->set * (max - min) + min ;

        ok = SetMonitorBrightness(
            pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor,
            dwv) ;

        eprintf("WINDOWS:brightness:set:dwv=%ld ok=%d\n", dwv, ok) ;
        }

    }
    }

    /* Close the monitor handles.
     */
    ok = DestroyPhysicalMonitors(
    nmonitor, 
    pPhysicalMonitors);

    /* Free the array.
     */
    free(pPhysicalMonitors);
 done:

    return 1 ;
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling a function named `GetPhysicalMonitors()` as you write in your question. Please take the time to carefully explain the issue you are having. If you need sample code, then stackoverflow is likely the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Fixed the error in description to say GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR (which MSDN says is recommended).  We don't care much what specific functions to use for this; we just want an approach.  We have spent a full day on this and can't understand what we could be doing wrong or why there are no available code snippets.  This should be really easy.